# PIG: Invalid field projection. Projected field [dept_no] does not exist in schema

Tags: apache-pig, grouping

I have two .csv files,

1) list of managers split by department name, employee ID, and date hired.

2) a file with ALL the employees, regardless of rank, and is divided by hire_date, first name, last_name.

I want to output all the **first and last names of *managers*** in a specific department labeled 'chem'.

I first load both files.

```
managers = LOAD....
employees = LOAD...
```

I then attempt a cogroup.

```
grouped = COGROUP emplo BY first_name, manag by dept_no;
```

And then try to filter out what comes out of grouped with the specific department

```
only_chem = FILTER grouped BY dept_no == 'chem';
```

But, when I DUMP the result, it says, in this last bit, Invalid field projection. Projected field [dept_no] does not exist in schema.

I must be doing something wrong in how I group them. I want to get rid of extraneous information but be able to filter out all the employees and only get the managers from those, but I need the large employee file since it has first/last name fields.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```
D = FOREACH grouped{
                      only_chem = FILTER  managers BY dept_no == 'chem';
                      GENERATE FLATTEN(only_chem);
                 }
DUMP D;
```

if this doesn't work, please paste your sample input data of employee and managers files and also 2 load stmt.

Comment: Thank you, while I had found a different solution using JOIN instead, I noticed this previous one wasn't working because I didn't flatten after the cogroup.